# How to set ordering for one-to-many relationship in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Say I have a Game object with many Player objects (a baseball game).  The lineup for each game has a specific ordering.

Are there any recommendations on how to store ordering for this scenario?

If it were only ONE game I could simply store an index in each Player object.  However, this ordering changes for each game.  And so if a Player object gets deleted I want to be sure the Game object gets updated as well (maintain referential integrity).

For what I am working on I will ALWAYS have from 2 to 4 players.

I tried to create a separate relationship for each player in the Game object, such as "playerOne", "playerTwo", etc.  However, when I try to create the inverse relationship in the Player object I can only set the "Game" relationship to one of the players ("playerOne", "playerTwo", etc).

The next thing I may try is to create four inverse relationships in the Player object to point specifically to the relationship in the Game object but I don't think it is correct and would be very messy.

Another option is that I could potentially store the full URL of each player object as a string in the Game object.  However, I would then need to manage deletions and so forth.

Any recommendations is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues in the past.  The way I personally went about it is to just index them.  Add some property, such as `index` for example.  Then whenever a change is made, call some local method that retags the indexes.  Here's a crude example that should give the basic logic

```
- (void)retagPlayers {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Players" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"game like %@", currentGame];
    NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *players = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    int index = 0;
    for (Player *player in players) {
        player.index = index;
        index++;
    }
}
```

This assumes a few things, so I should specify some of it.  In it, it assumes you have an Entity for your players called Players.  And that each has a relationship to a `game`, which is a string in this case.  These things may be different in your code and can be changed accordingly.  The logic is the same either way.  It basically searches your context for Player instances for a particular Game (using the predicate), then sorts them by index.  It then enumerates through that returned array and sets the new indexes to what they should be after the change.  I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I did mention using an index in my post. However, the order of each player is tied to each game, and must be stored somehow. Your example simply sets an index value starting from zero without regard to what the index should be.  I think I may just store the object URLs.

Comment: After some thought I think perhaps a global index could be applied to all Player objects 0..n.  Then, each Game object can store the four indexes, thus preserving the order of the players.  For example, playerOne = 8, playerTwo = 1, playerThree = 2, playerFour = 5.  A lookup method could be used to retrieve the Player corresponding to a respective index.  This may be difficult to do at the moment since I need to perform a data migration.  I will think about this some more.

Comment: In my example, I simply gave a way to update the values to keep them ordered prior to them initally being set.  That would be up to you to initialize.  I would have tried to give an example for that as well, but I didn't want to impose too much considering I don't know how your app is set up in that regard.  As long as you can set some initial order to your players, the above logic should help you maintain that order as you add/remove players

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you problem right you need a many-to-many relationship between "Game" and "Player", not a to-many. Moreover, as you need sorting capability for each relationship you have to create a completely new entity that manages:

1. The many-to-many relationship between "Game" and "Player"
2. The sorting for each "Player" regarding to one "Game" (and inverse)

I'd recommend an entity called "GamesPlayers" with two to-many relationships, one to the "Game" and one to the "Player" entity. Finally you need to add a sorting property – *I'd not call it "index" as this is a very common name often used by Apple in the Cocoa Framework*.

To Manage the sorting property being updated as relationships change, you should create a NSManagedObject subclass for "GamesPlayers", overwrite the `addGamesObject:` and `removeGamesObject:` as well as `addPlayersObject:` and `removePlayersObject:` entity.

Comment: Thanks Florian.  I think I could get something like this to work.  However, with much thought I think it would be best for me to add an iterative "index" property to each player, starting from zero. Then I can use this index value for playerOne, playerTwo, etc. It will require me to manage add/delete of players. I just thought of this solution this morning.